# No me funciona el EXCEPTION NO_DATA_FOUND en un PROCEDURE después de un FOR IN

Tags: oracle

¡Buenas noches! Soy nuevo y vengo con una duda que me tiene la cabeza loca.

Tengo este procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE apellidosDept (num IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
FOR fila IN (SELECT APELLIDO FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_NO = num) LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(fila.APELLIDO);
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END;
```

Pero no me detecta la excepción. ¿A qué puede ser debido? ¡Muchísimas gracias!

EDITO:

Al final, lo he solucionado con un contador:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE apellidosDept (num IN NUMBER)
IS
contador NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
FOR fila IN (SELECT APELLIDO FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_NO = num) LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(fila.APELLIDO);
contador := contador + 1;
END LOOP;
IF contador = 0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas `FOR fila IN (SELECT....` simplemente el programa entra o no al FOR y tendrías que usar una bandera para detectarlo. 
La exepción `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN` aplica si usas un cursor de la siguiente manera:

En el bloque de declaraciones (antes del BEGIN) declaras el cursor:

```
Cursor c (p_num NUMBER) IS 
SELECT APELLIDO FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_NO = p_num;
```

Declarar variable para leer el cursor:

```
r_c c%ROWTYPE;
```

y en el bloque del procedimiento haces lo siguiente:

1. Abrir el cursor

---

```
  OPEN c(num);
```

2. Leer

---

```
  LOOP
         EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND; 
          FETCH c INTO r_c;
          dbms_output.put_line(r_c.APELLIDO);
     END LOOP;
```

3. Cerrar el cursor

---

```
 CLOSE c;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END;
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por responder! La cuestión es que, desgraciadamente, sigue sin mostrarme la excepción "error" cuando paso por parámetro un número "DEPT_NO" que no aparezca en la tabla "EMP"